# Is there a way to choose this capacitance such that the system becomes non-oscillatory?

Tags: operational-amplifier, transfer-function, oscillation

Suppose we have this circuit with an ideal op-amp:

[image]

My question is whether it's possible to find a value of \$C_1\$ such that this system becomes non-oscillatory for a step as the input.

Here's how I'm thinking: First, we want to find the transfer function of this system.

I'm not so sure whether I found it correctly, either way, it's not really what's important here: $$ H(s) = \frac{1+sC_1R}{2+sR(C+C_1)+s^2R^2C C_1}$$

If we have a step response as our input, then \$U_o(s) = H(s) u_s(s) = H(s)/s\$.

My problem is that I don't really know how to make this system non-oscillatory from this. I'm thinking that the transfer function must have poles which are purely real and negative.

Is this the correct way of thinking? I'm new to this concept, so I'd be glad if anyone could present the main thought process for solving problems like these.

Comment: If you mean ripples in input for a step function, usually  capacitor \$C_1\$ is added before inverting terminal.  Try several methods.

Comment: @AmitM I'm sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough. I mean that we want a step response of this circuit such that it becomes non oscillatory. So no ripples, just the ordinary Heaviside step function as input.

Comment: A step function is non oscillatory. To do that, you have to remove all ripples/oscillations in input signal before it is amplified.

Comment: @AmitM Yes, I understand that bit. I mean that we want our $U_o$ to become non oscillatory after our step function input $U_s$ goes through the circuit.

Comment: "*it's not really what's important here*" -- that's precisely what's important: the transfer function dictates the system's response. By non-oscillatory, do you mean critically damped or overdamped (not underdamped)? I can't answer now but, maybe later.

Comment: You seem to try to feed a step signal to a op amp integrator, When the capacitor C is charging, the output signal would have a ramp which is not a step response. Op-amps also have a slew rate which causes output to have rise time of about 10 to 15 μs whether you have the capacitors or not.  If that rise time is acceptable, I got a step response like output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your transfer function is not the correct one but, since you don't show how you reached it, I can't pinpoint the error. This is the circuit in SPICE compared to its `Laplace` equivalent, you can see they completely overlap:

[image: correct Laplace transfer function]

The analysis goes like this: \$V_-=0\$ because it's a virtual ground.

$$\begin{align}
&\begin{cases}
0\cdot\left(\dfrac1R+\dfrac1R+sC\right)&=\dfrac{V_{\text{in}}}{R}+\dfrac{V_{\text{out}}}{R}+V_{\text{out}}sC+\dfrac{V_2}{2R} \\
V_2\cdot\left(\dfrac{1}{2R}+\dfrac{1}{2R}+sC_x\right)&=\dfrac{0}{2R}+\dfrac{V_{\text{out}}}{2R}
\end{cases} \\
\Rightarrow &\dfrac{V_{\text{out}}}{V_{\text{in}}}=-\dfrac{4(RC_xs+1)}{4R^2CC_xs^2+4R(C+C_x)s+5} \tag{1} \\
&=-\dfrac{1}{RC}\cdot\dfrac{s+\dfrac{1}{RC_x}}{s^2+\dfrac1R\left(\dfrac1C+\dfrac{1}{C_x}\right)s+\dfrac{5}{4}\cdot\dfrac{1}{R^2CC_x}} \tag{2}
\end{align}$$

This is a 2nd order transfer function so one of the three cases apply: underdamped (UD), critically damped (CD), and overdamped (OD). This means solving for the roots of the denominator and checking whether the discriminant is positive (OD), or negative (UD), or zero (CD):

$$\begin{align}
a&=4R^2CC_x \\
b&=4R(C+C_x) \\
c&=5 \\
s_{1,2}&=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a} \\
\Delta&=b^2-4ac=16R^2(C+C_x)^2-4\cdot 5\cdot 4R^2CC_x \\
\Rightarrow \\
\Delta&=16R^2(C^2+C_x^2-3CC_x) \\
&=C^2+C_x^2-3CC_x \tag{3}
\end{align}$$

\$16R^2\$ can be discarded since it's a positive definite constant. The discriminant is a quadratic of the form \$x^2-3ax+a^2\$ and it's a parabola, meaning it will have two values where it will be zero (CD):

$$C_x^{1,2}=\dfrac{(3\pm\sqrt5)C}{2} \tag{4}$$

Inside this interval the values will be negative and positive outside. The value you're looking for in the case of CD is \$C_x^1\$ (the one with \$-\sqrt5\$), in which case the step response reduces to:

$$\begin{align}
s(t)_{CD}&=\mathrm{e}^{-At}\left(\dfrac45-\dfrac{7\sqrt5-15}{5(3\sqrt5-7)RC}t\right)-\dfrac45 \tag{5} \\
A&=\dfrac{5-\sqrt5}{(2\sqrt5-6)RC}
\end{align}$$

The step (or impulse) response will not have any \$\sin()\$ or \$\sinh()\$ terms with \$C_x^2\$ but the response will have overshoot: the inverse Laplace will show that the \$t\$ term will not be negated by the \$\mathrm{e}^{-t}\$ term. I'll leave the math to you if you're curious.

At this point you have all you need to make your transfer function "overshootless". If you're willing to go the mathematical (strict) way then no overshoot will mean either CD or OD . If you're willing to accept some minor compromises then Gaussian approximation (+0.051%), or even Bessel (+0.433%) are also on the table. And, to prove the CD value:

[image: critically damped]

---

[edit]

There's one point I forgot to address: the zero in the numerator. This changes the game. Now it's no longer a case of "only the roots of the denominator", it's also about the zero. The step (or impulse) response need to be calculated through the inverse Laplace and you'll find that they are different. For example, if `R=1, C=1, Cx=10` the step responses for (2) vs (6) -- its equivalent without a zero (below) -- are these:

$$G(s)=\dfrac{4}{4R^2CC_xs^2+4R(C+C_x)s+5} \tag{6}$$

[image: the zero changes the response]

And, to make things more interesting, setting the quality factor to 0.5 will mean a CD case, for both (2) and (6) (see below, right) but, only for \$C_x^1\$ . For \$C_x^2\$ the responses will be in very different realms -- (2) will be UD while (6) will be OD (left):

[image: Q has a surprize effect]

For \$C_x^1\$, in both cases the quality factor will be Q=0.5 (CD) but, otherwise, they are different.

So, the lesson is: as long as there are zeroes, they need to be taken into account.

Comment: To the "concerned citizen": I think, there is one "weak" point in your answer resp. simulation: You have assumed an ideal opamp without any phase shift. When the question is about oscillatory behaviour, I think the non-ideal properties of the opamp play role that cannot be neglected from the beginning (without any further analyses).

Comment: @LvW That's true but, OP's transfer function follows the ideal case, so I simply presumed that those oscillations are about the overshoot in the step response. If it's not so, OP is welcome to correct me -- I'll oblige.

Comment: OP, I've updated the question to include the zero in the numerator.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for in an answer. Very clear!

Comment: @RussellH I'm looking through the edit history and all I see changed are minor wordings and math formatting. There isn't any change in the question, itself. Could it be that you scrolled past the OP's end of the question and think this is the question (and maybe the `[edit]` looked confusing)?

Comment: @RussellH Not a problem. Don't ask me how I got the insight...

Answer (score 4):

The denominator of \$H(s)\$ is called the characteristic polynomial. Apply the quadratic formula to it to obtain its zeros in the form of: \$x\pm y\$. If \$y\$ is real or zero, the TF is non- oscillatory. If \$y\$ is imaginary then there will be “ringing” or overshoot in response to a step.

The zeros of the denominator are the poles of \$H(s)\$.

Yes the real part of the poles must be negative for stability. Poles with an imaginary part will oscillate but will stabilize if the real part is negative.

Comment: While this is true, the zero in the numerator will change the response, so it's not enough to set the Q<=0.5. For example, `C1` can have two values where the discriminant is zero, and one of them will get a critically damped response for both OP's t.f. and the lowpass equivalent (no zero), but for the other, OP's t.f. will be underdamped, while the lowpass will be overdamped (see my answer).

Answer (score 1):

You're exactly on the right path. As was commented, the transfer function is exactly what's important in these analyses. Without going through and solving it, you should first find the transfer function as you did. With the transfer function, you can then solve for the poles. As you stated, you want the poles to be real and negative. Any positive poles indicate an unstable system. Any imaginary poles indicate oscillation will occur.

Here's a good intro reference on the topic:
https://web.mit.edu/2.14/www/Handouts/PoleZero.pdf

Comment: "Any positive poles" should read  "any poles with positive real parts". The phrase "positive poles" really has no meaning. 
"imaginary poles" indicates sinusoidal oscillation of constant magnitude. Complex poles indicate overshoot or ringing.

Comment: Yes, thanks for clarifying my answer.

Comment: @mech-eng_doing_ee The clarification is up to you to add to/modify your question, not to leave in the comments section (hich are not idexed when searching, so contents will be lost tha tway).